# proper ios5 storyboard flow for a constant background / transparent views?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard

I have one background I want constant to all views; it shouldn't animate out and back to itself. I have another background I want common to another handful of views that layers on top of that one. I could do this cleanly enough by:

a) just having one viewcontroller and managing all the transitions of layered objects within that
b) using separate viewcontollers and managing them programatically

But I don't grok how I can do this with a storyboard proper-like. Do I need to make a custom segue? Is there a certain *type* of segue it should be, if it's custom (or otherwise)? Is there a best viewcontroller that I do it all inside? (note: there's no "levels" of navigation, tab bar, navbar, etc... though if that's the way to go, with the elements hidden, and that's the "best" way to do it, I suppose that that might be me c)? )

Hope I've explained this well enough. :) I *do* grok layer transparency, etc, as far as views go....

Thanks!

ETA: After more research, I thought I understood c as the correct answer, (with a nod to [set "default" UIViewController background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592576/set-default-uiviewcontroller-background-image) ) ~

- navigation controller with main background

  - navigation controller with secondary background elements

    - subpage 1
    - subpage 2
    - subpage 3
  - other controller

But I'm still hitting a wall. Not grokking the storyboard (IB) way to even add a background to a navigation controller. The number of custom classes I've made and tossed out, now....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this is what you need. It is not in storyboard, but should do well enough.

```
navViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];
```

This is what I have done (but only with 1 level of nav controller). You can put this code in AppDelegate.m, or maybe subclass UINavigationViewController and change the view's backgroundColor there (and attach it within StoryBoard)

I guess the problem is StoryBoard still has some limitations. And UINavigationViewController is not an interface element, it is a View Controller. It is simply shown as a simulated element in StoryBoard.)

Comment: The problem is that I want that image background to remain there across multiple views. Maybe what I want is along the lines of:

Comment: doh. didn't realize I had to shift-enter for a new line. And then took too long finishing the edit (actually writing the comment).

* view
** subview [interactive, with viewcontroller]
** subview [noninteractive for background that shows up with "most" views, controlled by delegate?]
** subview [noninteractive for background that shows on *all* views]

Doesn't get elements up into the storyboard, which is lame, but maybe that's the right way to go? At the moment, I've got a weird subviewcontroller thing going on, which I think is the wrong way of thinking about it, though it's working....

Comment: Strange. It works for me... 

Have you changed the background of your views to transparent? (Opacity 0)

Comment: Ah, I misread you, sorry. That seems to do it, even with nested UINavigationControllers. I think I just had myself looped through too many different thoughts. Thanks! Shame it can't be done in storyboard yet.